# RelativeLayout positioning issue with first child LinearLayout using margin

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, margins

I'm currently trying to position some LinearLayouts (which are then filled with some images) on an absolute position on the screen. Currently the LinearLayouts are alinged to the top-left of the parent RelativeLayout and then positioned using margins. This works properly for all child LinearLayouts EXCEPT the first one in the list. Setting some margins (as for example 25dp for the left margin) does not show any effect in this case. I hope someone has had the same issue and can provide some guidance.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_page"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_first" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_second" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginLeft="175dp" android:layout_marginTop="30dp"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_third" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" android:layout_marginTop="140dp"></LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit: 
Example image https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuYjU.jpg

Comment: The layouts are added one on top of each other. Even the first one is put where you expect, just that the second and third will draw on top of first one and anything you put there will be over-drawn. Try better to put them one AFTER another.

Comment: See my comment below .. unfortunately this did not solve the case :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RelativeLayout provides some tags for the positioning of Views/ViewGroups relative to another View/ViewGroup.

- `android:layout_below="id"` and `android:layout_above="id"`
  This will put the View below/above another View with the id.
- `android:layout_alignRightOf="id"` and `android:layout_alignLeftOf="id"`
  This will put the View to the right/left of another View with the id.

All tags have the same usability like this, where I use the android:layout_below="" to set a View/ViewGroup below another:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_page"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <--! YOUR LAYOUT AT THE TOP OF YOUR PARENT -->
    <LinearLayout 
         android:id="@+id/ll_first"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"

         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_second"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"

         android:layout_below="@id/ll_first" ></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
         android:id="@+id/ll_third" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"

         android:layout_below="@id/ll_second"></LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now you can use some margins for the position of every View.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of this tags. I removed them some time ago due to the fact that by using them I had to define the margins relative to the above element. I have reverted the code back to using this tags and adapted the margins. Unfortunately the positioning issue still persists with the first LinearLayout child of the RelativeLayout. (I can provide the code plus a screenshot if you want.)

Comment: One workaround would be to add proper padding to the RelativeLayout to position the first child properly, but this would also comes with some downsides.

Comment: @AustrianDude I just recognized there is no orientation in your LinearLayouts. Have you solved the problem already?

Comment: Thanks for your help I can't believe I forgot that. In the course fixing this issue I recognized the final mistake that cause the described problem: In my source code I was adding the drawable resources to all LinearLayouts properly EXCEPT for the first one. In this case I was adding the drawable to the RelativeLayout. That caused the image to always hug the top-left corner.